# How to implement restful webservice with python/django

Tags: python, django, web-services

i try to setup a ubuntu server with web service that create by django/python , anyone have an resource/tutorial/example code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is also [piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home), which is a Django framework for creating RESTful APIs.  It has a slight learning curve, but nicely fits into Django.

If you want something more lightweight, Simon Willison has very [nice snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1071/) that I have used previously that nicely models the HTTP methods:

```
class ArticleView(RestView):

    def GET(request, article_id):
        return render_to_response("article.html", {
            'article': get_object_or_404(Article, pk = article_id),
        })

    def POST(request, article_id):
        # Example logic only; should be using django.forms instead
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk = article_id)
        article.headline = request.POST['new_headline']
        article.body = request.POST['new_body']
        article.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

Jacob Kaplan-Moss has a nice article on [Worst Practices in REST](http://jacobian.org/writing/rest-worst-practices/) that can help guide you away from some common pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

See [the chapter on non-html content in the Django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter13/).

Comment: A link to an external site is not an answer, and should not be posted as such. This should be a comment to the original post, as you've provided no information to make it an actual answer that will be useful in a search in the future.